# Настройка nginx для работы с django и vue c ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl

Пытаюсь задеплоить свой пет проект на DRF и Vuejs.
Приобрел VPS, настроил gunicorn и nginx по гайдам, он работал. Потом настроил ssl при помощи certbot и при попытке зайти на сайт по http, открывается страница провайдера доменов (reg.ru), где сказано, что "домен зарегистрирован и припаркован". По https работает нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста, что тут не так. Ну или это может быть не с этим проблема?

```
server {
    server_name site.ru www.site.ru;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/site/reviews_django;
    }
    
    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/site/reviews_django;
    }
    
    location /api {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    
    location /admin {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/site/reviews_vue/dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;   

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.site.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = site.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name site.ru www.site.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Почистьте кэш браузера?

Comment: у вас редирект внизу стоит с http на https...должно работать

Comment: Ну вот странновато. С мобильного телефона вроде работает, но с пк все равно показывает заглушку reg.ru. Сейчас прям скачал другой браузер и с него тоже заглушка. И с другого ПК тоже. Кеш и куки очистил вроде. curl показывает 301 статус как и должно быть.

Comment: А в DNS-записях случайно не бардак? Вдруг несколько A-записей, ведущих на разные серверы?

Comment: Да, похоже это в моем пк проблема, сейчас на работе попробовал и все нормально. В общем буду разбираться, спасибо.